# PHP Mysqli: Multi-key search form

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I want to create a form which allows the user to type in a search with different field and have it pick up the right values from a database and display them. For some reasons, I can't figure out know how the search page will be define with Mysqli queries.

How can I create a `search.php` page that displays a record from a table according to search form and mysqli queries?

Here's what I've tried so far:

**PHP Code:**

```
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "root";
$DBpass = "";
$DBname = "search";

$DBcon = new MySQLi($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBname);

if ($DBcon->connect_errno) {
    die("ERROR : -> ".$DBcon->connect_error);
}

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $query = mysqli_query($DBcon,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE name LIKE '%" .  $_POST['name'] . "%'
          OR address LIKE '%" . $_POST['address'] . "%'
          OR city LIKE '%" . $_POST['city'] . "%'
          OR state LIKE '%" . $_POST['state'] . "%'") or die ("Could not search");
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MySQL table search</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
        BODY, TD {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form action ="index.php" method = "post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="state" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
    <?php echo ("$output");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If yes, show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. If not, try something first and if you run into some _specific_ issue, come back and show us what you've tried. This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sir i past my query above but not working help me i am just beginner

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Please define _"not working"_. Do you get the wrong results? Error messages? Checked the error log? Btw, you're making a query but you're not doing anything with the results. `$output` will always be empty.

Comment: `echo ("$output");` can be reduced to: `echo $output;`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you who like to search through table in sql and echo the output. So here i have used mysqli with sql LIKE operator to search for pattern as per user.

NOTE : In sql query i have used `LIKE tblname %$vars%` , you can also use this way `%$vars%` but both have different meaning . To Know more visit this [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Output image is given below :
[image: Output image]

```
 <?php

$link = new mysqli ('localhost','root','admin','demo');
if($link->connect_error){
    die("failed to connect".$link->connect_error);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form action ="" method = "post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="state" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
            $output = '';
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $state = $_POST['state'];

            $sql = "SELECT name,address,city,state FROM sql_like_operator WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' OR address LIKE '%$address%' OR  city LIKE '%$city%' OR state LIKE '%$state%'";

            $res= $link->query($sql);

            if($res->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                    $output .= $row['name']."<br>";
                    $output .= $row['address']."<br>";
                    $output .= $row['city']."<br>";
                    $output .= $row['state']."<br>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        }
    ?>

    <h5><?php echo @$output;?></h5>
</body>
</html>
```